# Can't detect NaN values in dataframe (python)

Tags: python, pandas, osmnx

I have a geodataframe obtained from osmnx:

```
cities = ox.geocode_to_gdf(['Município de Lisboa', 'Município de Oeiras', 'Município da Amadora', 'Município de Loures', 'Município de Odivelas'])
whole_polygon = cities.unary_union #unary union of both geometries
G = ox.graph_from_polygon(whole_polygon, network_type='drive', simplify=True)
G_nx = nx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G)

nodes, edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G_nx, nodes=True, edges =  True)
```

[image]

I was trying to identify when the values of the `name` column were `NaN` but for some reason it cannot detect:

```
for i in range(len(edges)):

    if edges['name'].iloc[i] == float('nan'):
        print('here')
```

I have tried `float('NaN')` instead of what is in the code. I checked that when the `name` value is `NaN` the variable is indeed a float. There are three types of values in the name column: `list`, `str`, `float`, where floats are only when the value is `NaN`

Comment: `if edges['name'].isnull():`
`print('here')`
Does this work

Comment: That doesnt work no

Comment: `if edges['name'].iloc[i].isnull(): print('here')` forgot the `iloc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {"h":[1,np.nan,2]}
pd.DataFrame(data).isnull()

#output
    h
0   False
1   True
2   False
```

Comment: Oh I see, that does work yes. I forgot that the data might actually be missing and not be an actual float